# Referencing sheets by index number

Tags: vba, excel

I am creating a model that asks users to input parameters (year, region, risktype), and return values associated with them.  The returned values will change depending on the year and region that they input.  At the moment, I trying to create a `for loop` that searches across multiple sheets.  I am only focused on the region, and will work on the year input later.  I created two functions to get the index numbers of the sheets in question:

```
'creates index number for first needed sheet, used to locate projected scores
Public Function GetStartIndex() As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    GetStartIndex = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LMC_Model").Index + 1
End Function

'creates index number for final sheet, used to locate projected scores
Public Function GetEndIndex() As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    GetEndIndex = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Other").Index - 2 'ensures that we get correct sheet
End Function
```

Later on, I have a section with the actual `for loop`.

```
indexStart = GetStartIndex()
indexEnd = GetEndIndex()
riskLookupScore = Application.VLookup(risk, ws9.range("G10:H14"), 2)

For i = indexStart To indexEnd
    If i = riskLookupScore Then
        Cells(16, 4).Value = Application.VLookup(region, ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).range("c3:c11"), 0)
    End If
Next i
```

The `riskLookupScore` variable is assigned a number used for matching in the `for loop`.  When I run the code, however, I get a 'NA' value for my result.  I feel as though referencing the sheet used with `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).range("c3:c11")` is where this is occurring.  Can anyone offer any advice?

Comment: comment out the `On Error Resume Next` and see where it hangs.  That will give a better idea where your problem lays.

Comment: Tried this, but nothing changed.

Comment: set up a breakpoint and verify that the value of `region` is found in the data range.  the error is stating it cannot find the value in the region.

Comment: `0` as the third parameter of `VLookup` is definitely causing problems.

Comment: Good catch.  I corrected that mistake, but still get the N/A value.

Comment: Will you fix the code in your original post to reflect the change you made?

Comment: Will do.  Actually, I found teh error is it was quite stupid.  My `vlookoup` range was not correct.  Apologies for wasting time.

Comment: One more thing: you don't need a loop, `If` and `index...` variables. Simply replace `i` with `riskLookupScore` in the second `Vlookup`

Comment: Whats `region`? could be that `region` is a range defined on another sheet than the one you are using the VLookUp in. This could cause a problem.